# Programmatically opening a file, receive message when closed - OSX/Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

First off, I’m fairly new to OSX development…

I have an NSTableView that contains a list of encrypted files that the user can double click to decrypt and open, when the user has finished editing/viewing the file I would like the application to re-encrypt the file.
On Windows, I can decrypt, open, then use WaitForSingleObject to sit and wait for the process to complete [so I can re-encrypt]

Is there a way I can do this on OSX/Swift?

I’ve tried using an NSTask using ‘bash open -X -path’ which potentially works, problem being it sits and waits for the process to terminate which is a problem for some Apps as they don’t automatically terminate after a document is closed.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of files will they be? Will it be any kind of file? Is it a file that only your app can open and edit?

Comment: You can add any file which the App will then encrypt, the encrypted file will then only be readable by my App.

So if a user wants to view or edit an encrypted file my App will first decrypt the file to a temp location then open the original file using the correct App. Later, when the user finishes editing the file my App needs to be informed so it can re-encrypt the file (including any changes made)

Comment: That is an interesting problem. How about monitoring the file for changes instead? I think there is a Framework called FSEvents.